# bootstrap-datepicker disable next month view in current month

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using Bootstrap date picker [Bootstrap Date Picker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&maxViewMode=2&todayBtn=false&clearBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox) I want to hide next month dates showing in current month screen, i.e. February have 29 days. so calendar just display Feb month from 01 till 29, don't display march few dates [See the Screen](http://prntscr.com/a4mmy6) this is i don't want to show.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could hide the rest after disabling them. You can first disable using http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#id5 and then hide them using:

```
function hide_disabled_dates()
{
    $(".day.disabled").css("display", "none");
}
```

Oh and if you can't use enddate, then do:

```
function hide_disabled_dates()
{
    $(".day.new").css("display", "none");
}
```

To clarify, the second solution I put will work if you use enddate or not, so you should probably use that one instead.